# Property 'swiper' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, swiper.js

I have a Warning in VsCode: "Property 'swiper' does not exist on type 'never'".
I don`t know how to fix it, may be someone encounter this problem?

Don`t see answers in google either.

Comment: How do you try to use it? It looks like you are trying to get swiper as a property of some object. Where and how did you initialize it? Can you share the code?

Comment: Here is usage code: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-example-832g6k